# Importing CSV into Realm Browser workflow

Tags: csv, converters, realm, realm-migration

The first question is which CSV to import, which is fine.
The second question is where to put the new Realm file? Any suggestions? I have been rewriting the default.realm object inside my default configuration URL.

However, when I go to import a second CSV (I have about 8 in total), I am presented the same questions. If I choose the same folder to put the new Realm file, I over-write it and lose my first model.

Is there something basic I'm missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Realm Browser 1.0.2 was released with support of importing multiple CSV files an once, so now you can select all your files in Open Dialog and import it's data.

Browser will create a realm file in the destination you specify, I suggest you to not override the existing file just in case of any errors,

Comment: what if I need to specify a field as PrimaryKey? I can't do that in CSV. I should update existing table with CVS data